# How to add stroke to text frame in Illustrator using Applescript?

Tags: applescript, border, adobe-illustrator, stroke

```
set mytexts to make new text frame with properties {contents:"Annonation " & g & ":" & param_Text, kind:area text, position:{(-150), (new_Var)}, width:(checkValue3 - checkValue1), name:"notes"}
```

Above code is used to create text in Illustrator using Applescript. How to add stroke or border to the created text frame. Any references or advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Include a bit more code in your question, best to simplify it with a working snippet that targets Illustrator (hard code all those variables). Making it as easy as possible for us to test the code will increase your chances of an answer.

Comment: @adamh I dont have more codes to create text frame. Others are `If` and `Else` condition. Above code can write text frame in Illustrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text Path.

```
set properties of text path of mytexts to {stroked:true, stroke width:0.1}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it's a little hard to tell what you're asking for.

Are you trying to add a stroke to the outside of your text frame, like you might do in the appearance panel? Something like this?

[image]

If so, then you're out of luck. There's no access to extra strokes and fills from within scripting ([source](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1344590)).

But maybe you just want to apply a stroke to the text, to give it an outline. Something like this.

[image]

In that case, this is the AppleScript you want to use

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
            -- customize this as needed for your app
    set theFrame to (make new text frame in current document with properties ¬
        {contents:"My text", kind:area text, name:¬
            "notes"})
    set theRange to text range of theFrame
    set stroke color of theRange to {red:45, green:20, blue:128}
end tell
```